# How to add css classes in sitefinity CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, content-management-system, sitefinity

I am new sitefinity. I have completed css files and images with me to create my first project in sitefinity. But can anybody help me how i can add this to App_Data via file manager of Sitefinity? Is there any naming convention?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to register your theme: http://docs.sitefinity.com/register-a-theme

If you don't already have your theme file structure set up see this: http://docs.sitefinity.com/overview-themes

Note that Sitefinity often tells you that you have a choice of where to put your theme files, but what they don't tell you is that your CSS file will only be auto-versioned if you put it in this folder: /App_Data/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/[YourTemplate]/App_Themes/[YourTheme]

Comment: No. Now i got my css files but its classes are overriding by Sitefinity's classes.

Comment: @SajnaAli did my answer not address your original question? Sitefinity injects a lot of markup and css, if you are having trouble with that you should ask another question or at least describe the issue in more detail.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your comment answered my question. Now i registered my theme and applied that to my template. But still when i am "previewing" it, the class names that i have given for certain blocks are overriding with Sitefinity classes.
Eg: my class is content and when the page loads its coming as "sf-cols content". @wentz

Comment: @SajnaAli my experience has definitely been that Sitefinity adds in a lot of these sf-cols classes. Hopefully this helps: http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/designing-styling/page-template-layout-class-css-being-overridden-

Comment: Thank you! but you can see my comment as a last one in that link. Right now i am trying to over ride the sitefinity classes. Other than this cant we block their classes and styles??